# Which configuration is missing?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, devops

I created a website, and now i'm trying to get it online.

I have a VM in oracle cloud it is ubuntu 22.04. And my website is React JS.

Here is everything that I've done so far.

Connected to server and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y node
sudo apt-get install -y npm
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
```

Then, locally I run `npm build`

Then I zip the build folder and send it to server with `scp`

Again in server I created a folder `~/app` and un unzip the build inside it.

So I try to config nginx like this:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/defaut**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen [::]:8000 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name realrapido.com www.realrapido.com;

        location / {
                root /home/ubuntu/app/build;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

After change the file I run `sudo nginx -t` to be sure that everything was ok.

Then I restarted the nginx with `sudo service nginx stop` and `sudo service nginx start`.

I`m sure that DNS is correctly pointed to oracle cloud IP.

but I cant connect the site yet. What do I missing?

Thank you for helping. I'm not devOps ^^ but I'm trying to create my website alone.

---

Edited:

I forgot to mention that I configured allowed ports with `ufw`

I enabled it with `sudo ufw enable`

And I started to allow the ports with `sudo ufw allow xyz`

Allowed ports so far are: `sudo ufw status verbose`

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```